# PowerShell - How to package custom modules into a zip package for AWS Lamdba

Tags: powershell, aws-lambda

I am trying to package a script I have as a Lambda function. The script loads some functions from some other ps1 files in the same folder. Currently use "." to include.
When I try to use `New-AWSPowerShellLambdaPackage -ProjectDirectory projectName -OutputPackage projectName.zip` to package the script files, it keeps failing with error below.

```
Line |
 253 |              throw $msg
     |              ~~~~~~~~~~
     | Error publishing PowerShell Lambda Function: -1 CALLSTACK: Command                        Arguments                                                                                                   Location -------
     | ---------                                                                                                   -------- _packageProject
     | {OutputPackage=C:\Users\tom\projectName\projectname.zip, BuildDirectory=projectName} _DeploymentFunctions.ps1: line 251 New-AWSPowerShellLambdaPackage {ProjectDirectory=projectName,
     | OutputPackage=projectName.zip}                                                       New-AWSPowerShellLambdaPackage.ps1: line 182 <ScriptBlock>                  {}
     | <No file>
```

Is this because I use "." to source the other ps1 files? Should I convert them into modules?
Anyone can suggest any documentation for this?
I can't seem to find any good source detailing how to package PowerShell lambda. All the examples I can find are for single ps1 file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a proper `.csproj` file to be able to use `-ProjectDirectory` switch.

I typically use the following procedure:

1. Generate project structure using `New-AWSPowerShellLambdaPackage` with `-StagingDirectory` switch:

   ```bsh
   New-AWSPowerShellLambdaPackage -StagingDirectory projectName -ScriptPath .\projectName.ps1 -OutputPackage projectName.zip
   ```
2. Modify `projectName.csproj` to include additional files. Following example adds `additionalScript.ps1` and all files within `SQL` folder into the package:

   ```xml
   <ItemGroup>
       <Content Include="projectName.ps1">
           <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
       </Content>
       <Content Include="additionalScript.ps1">
           <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
       </Content>
       <Content Include="./SQL/**">
           <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
       </Content>
       <Content Include="./Modules/**">
           <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
       </Content>
   </ItemGroup>
   ```
3. Use `New-AWSPowerShellLambdaPackage` with `-ProjectDirectory` switch to build the package:

   ```bsh
   New-AWSPowerShellLambdaPackage -ProjectName projectName -OutputPackage projectName.zip
   ```

Comment: Dmitry, this is a great response. The best I've seen so far on the topic of using `New-AWSPowerShellLambdaPackage` to generate a Lambda package with dependencies. However, I think need an **edit to the code in step 3**. The code should be:

`New-AWSPowerShellLambdaPackage -ProjectDirectory projectName -OutputPackage projectName.zip -DisableModuleRestore`